# JMeter XPath Extractor SAXEXception UTF-8

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I have been using JMeter's XPath extractor successfully for various pages of a website. So far I have been able to extract links using the following XPath expression:

> //div[@class='example']/a/@href

On a very similar page I have been unable to retrieve the same links even though they still reside in the same div structure as above. I added an `XPath Assertion` and got the following SAXException:

> SAXException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence

Can anyone help me understand what is going on.

```
XPath Extractor settings:
-------------------------
- Apply to: Main sample only
- XML parsing options: 
    Use Tidy (tolerant parser) = true
    Quiet = true
```

Thanks in advance.

*Edit: I am parsing HTML*

Comment: Show or put  somewhere the response you get so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the page you are trying to parse wasn’t UTF-8 encoded:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091158/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-invalid-byte-2-of-3-byte-utf-8-sequence)