# response.asXml() always returns encoding error on Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm making play framweork application.
I tried to get xml content from web services.
http://example.com/api returns xml, but its encoding is EUC-JP. (charset=euc-jp)

I wrote the following code.

```
WSRequest request = ws.url("http://example.com/api");
WSRequest complexRequest = request.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
    .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Promise<Document> documentPromise = complexRequest.post("key1=value1").map(response -> {
    String name = XPath.selectText("//name", response.asXml());
    System.out.println("name :" + name);
    return response.asXml();
});
```

However, response.asXml() always returns error :

```
[Fatal Error] :xx:xx: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

How can I get data by using response.asXml without any error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545720/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used DocumentBuilder on behalf of asXml, like 
[How to fix Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545720/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence)

```
  Promise<Result> resultPromise = request.post("key=" + value).map(response -> {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBody().getBytes("euc-jp"));
    String name = XPath.selectText("//name", builder.parse(stream)));
    System.out.println("name :" + name);

    return ok(main.render());
  });
```