# Getting error while executing report with jasperreport

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to get a report by using jasper report libraries but  I get an error
 "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence."

```
     private JasperPrint prepareReport(EnumList.JRList report) {
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            String jasperResource = "/reports/" + report.getName() + ".jasper";
            InputStream jasperStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(jasperResource);
            //InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(jasperStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            JasperReport jasperReport = 
   JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperStream);
            Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            JRDesignStyle jrDesignStyle = new JRDesignStyle();
            //jrDesignStyle.setPdfEncoding("UTF-8");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, conn);

            return jasperPrint;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("reportPrepareError: " + report.getName());
            return null;
        }
    }

   public static JasperReport compileReport(InputStream inputStream) throws JRException 
  {
        return getDefaultInstance().compile(inputStream);
    }

  public JasperReport compile(InputStream inputStream) throws JRException {
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
        return this.compile(jasperDesign);
    }
```

Comment: Probably problem in your jrxml (it can't be parsed correctly) see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545720/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .jasper file would normally contain an already compiled report.

Therefore you don't need to do `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperStream)` but

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
```