# Python3 Simple_Salesforce

Tags: python-3.x, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to connect my salesforce account with simple_salesforce through python.

im using this code

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username='username', password='password', security_token='token', sandbox=True)
```

when i run the code i get this error:

> simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceAuthenticationFailed: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.

according to documentation (https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) my code is the same as described.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. How are you storing your username, password, and security_token? And by that I mean, what's the encoding of the file? You might need to try something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057236/5051310)

Comment: @Terminus, i think it has to do with my username cause is like this: erjon.kelleçi. The letter ç i think is causing the problem