# Jenkins agent failed to start up

Tags: java, jenkins

My jenkins agent failed to start up, and showing something weird. I know the error is something related to file encoding, but not sure how to fix it.

Jenkins master version: 2.319
The slave is running on Raspberry Pi, master is AMD64

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/jenkins_agent/slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins.chenny.homes/computer/venus/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret xxxxx -workDir "/home/pi/jenkins_agent/workspace"
Nov 12, 2021 10:43:49 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/pi/jenkins_agent/workspace/remoting as a remoting work directory
Nov 12, 2021 10:43:49 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/pi/jenkins_agent/workspace/remoting
Failed to obtain http://jenkins.chenny.homes/computer/venus/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:701)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:567)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1895)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1761)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1799)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:156)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:806)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.loadDom(Launcher.java:607)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:547)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:347)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:298)
Waiting 10 seconds before retry
```

My encoding is set UTF-8, not sure how it can be wrong

```
awt.toolkit sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
casc.jenkins.config /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs
executable-war  /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
file.encoding   UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg   sun.io
file.separator  /
```

Comment: 1. find out which (xml!) file is causing this...2. then https://stackoverflow.com/q/15545720/592355 (fix the encoding...also typical error message for "windows utf-8" (with BOM) ;)

Comment: I know it is encoding related, but it is a jenkis slave agent, it is the file `http://<Jenkins master>/computer/venus/jenkins-agent.jnlp`, seems I have to create an issue for jenkins slave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this documentation](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/adding-a-jenkins-agent-node) to use `Launch Slave Agents via SSH` instead of `Launch agent by connecting it to the controller` as a walkaround, which works for me