# Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence error in PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While Syncing the Test cases scripts of PAF to ALM, getting error as below.

> "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
> Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence."

How to resolve ?

Comment: maybe this helps to identify the root cause of the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545720/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence

Comment: If you create the XML file manually - make sure that it has the correct file encoding and it does not contain non-uft characters